# Communication Between Two Controllers; References vs Primatives

Tags: angularjs, pass-by-reference, angular-services, angular-controller

I have seen an unexpected behaviour in Angularjs with its factories.
I used a factory to communication between two controllers.

In the first scenario it is working fine but not in second one. The only difference between them is that in first example I am accessing the name from the view but in second one I am accessing in scope variable.

**Scenario 1**

```
<div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    <a ng-click="setValue('jhon')">click</a>
</div>
<br />
<div ng-controller="GoodbyeCtrl">
    <p>{{fromFactory.name}}</p>
</div>

//angular.js example for factory vs service
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.factory('testFactory', function() {
        var obj = {'name':'rio'};
        return {
            get : function() {
                return obj;
            },
            set : function(text) {
               obj.name = text;
            }
        }          
    });

    function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory) {
        $scope.setValue = function(value) {
            testFactory.set(value);
        }
    }

    function GoodbyeCtrl($scope, testFactory) {
        $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.get();
    }
```

**Scenario 2**

```
<div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    <a ng-click="setValue('jhon')">click</a>
</div>
<br />
<div ng-controller="GoodbyeCtrl">
    <p>{{fromFactory}}</p>
</div>

//angular.js example for factory vs service
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.factory('testFactory', function() {
        var obj = {'name':'rio'};
        return {
            get : function() {
                return obj;
            },
            set : function(text) {
               obj.name = text;
            }  
        }               
    });

    function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory) {
        $scope.setValue = function(value) {
            testFactory.set(value);
        }
    }
    function GoodbyeCtrl($scope, testFactory) {
        $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.get().name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is:

### Scenario I

```
$scope.fromFactory = testFactory.get(); 

<div ng-controller="GoodbyeCtrl">
<p>  {{fromFactory.name}}</p>
</div>
```

The `$scope` variable is set to `testFactory.get()` which is an object *reference*. On each digest cycle the watcher fetches the value of the property `name` using the object reference. The DOM gets updated with changes to that property.

### Scenario II

```
$scope.fromFactory = testFactory.get().name;

<div ng-controller="GoodbyeCtrl">
    <p>{{fromFactory}}</p>
</div>
```

The `$scope` variable is set to `testFactory.get().name` which is a *primative*. On each digest cycle, the primative value doesn't change.

The important difference is that when a reference value is passed to a function, and a function modifies its contents, that change is seen by the caller and any other functions that have references to the object.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer, Appreciate your effort.